# JSP: Countdown timer not working?

Tags: java, jsp

GET METHOD:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Writes to htmlPage
        final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        // init CountDownTimer TODO: Understand why this doesn't work
        CountdownTimer timer = new CountdownTimer(CountdownTimer.toMili(5));
        timer.start(new OnWaiting() {

            @Override
            public void onFinished() {
                writer.println("Timer Finished");
            }
        });
        // getting params from url '?'
        final String userName = request.getParameter(USER_NAME);
        final String passWord = request.getParameter(PASS_WORD);
        // authentication step
        if (isValidUser(userName, passWord)) {
            writer.println(VALID);
        } else {
            writer.println(INVALID_USER_NAME + " or " + INVALID_PASS_WORD);
        }
    }
```

Specifically this part:

```
CountdownTimer timer = new CountdownTimer(CountdownTimer.toMili(5));
        timer.start(new OnWaiting() {

            @Override
            public void onFinished() {
                writer.println("Timer Finished");
            }
        });
```

Countdown class:

```
public class CountdownTimer {
    private final int mili;

    public CountdownTimer(int mili) {
        this.mili = mili;
    }

    public void start(final OnWaiting waiting) {
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(mili);
                    waiting.onFinished();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public static final int toMili(int seconds) {
        return seconds * 1000;
    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface OnWaiting {
    public void onFinished();

}
```

Why doesn't this work in a JSP? It works under a regular java project. I want to do this via java not javascript in the JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because once the servlet Get method finishes the communication with the client is closed. HTTP is normally a [Request-response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response) protocol with the exception of [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) therefore sending anything to the response once it's finished won't have any effect.

You can try an ajax request after the page is loaded.